# Is it possible to plot coraviance matrices in rxplot?

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Morning all,

I am trying to plot a few msgs on rxplot, which works perfectly fine for 1D. But when I try plotting the covariance matrix given in the message type geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped, nothing is plotted on the screen but my terminal is filled with the covariance values over time, along with the error message: "value was not numeric" . My command looks as follows:

rxplot /< namespace >/ < msg > /pose/covariance

Is there something I have missed? Is it even possible to plot variables of multiple dimensions? I would further like to be able to declare which elements of the matrix to plot (only diagonal values) if it is possible.

### Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217476/is-it-possible-to-plot-coraviance-matrices-in-rxplot?/) by [Kirjain](https://answers.ros.org/users/23835/kirjain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot plot a multi-dimentional value on a timeline. You can probably plot a single value from the matrix.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0